# How to call this.callParent from SetTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, extjs5

In Grouping grid i want to show masking so i put my code in setTimeout but in code i am calling super class function but its not working and if i remove setTimeOut its work properly

My Code Snippest is:

```
 onGroupClick: function (grid, node, group, event, eOpts) {
        var me = this;
        grid.mask(LAN.loading);
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (event && grid) {
                var isExpanded = grid.features[0].isExpanded(group);
                var target = event.getTarget('.' + me.targetCls);
                var store = grid.getStore();
                var groupRecord = me.getRecordGroup(event.record);
                if (target && store && groupRecord) {
                    if (!isExpanded) {
                        grid.features[0].expand(group);
                    }
                    var checked = target.checked;
                    this.updatingRecords = true;
                    groupRecord.each(function (rec, index) {
                        rec.set(me.checkDataIndex, checked);
                        rec.commit();
                    }, me);
                    me.updatingRecords = false;
                    me.refreshView();
                    me.fireEvent('onGroupCheck', groupRecord, checked);
                    if (!isExpanded) {
                        grid.features[0].collapse(group);
                    }
                } else {
                    me.superclass.onGroupClick(grid, node, group, eOpts).call();
                }
            }
            grid.unmask();
        }, 1);
    },
```

Comment: can you provide a descrition of the error? What exactly happening when it doesnt wort? What error message does your console show you?

Comment: Error is
Error: Attempting to call a protected method from the public scope, which is not allowed
    at constructor.callParent (ext-all-debug.js?16.2.0.3:13094)
    at constructor.eval (CheckboxGroupingFeature.js:149)

Comment: Can you setup a Sencha Fiddle. It would be much easier to help you that way.